# I am unable to get 'file' #type to appear in my form

Tags: forms

I am building a custom module where the user needs to upload an image.  Here is the code for my form:

```
function floor_map_form($form, &$form_state) {
        $form['file'] = array(
            '#type '        => 'file',
            '#title'        => t('Choose a file'),
        );
        $form['center'] = array(
            '#type'     => 'textfield',
            '#title'        => t('Center'),
            );
        $form['country'] = array(
            '#type'     => 'textfield',
            '#title'        => t('Country'),
            );
        $form['region'] = array(
            '#type'     => 'textfield',
            '#title'        => t('Region'),
            );
        $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type'     => 'submit',
            '#value'    => t('Submit'),
            );

        return $form;
    }
```

The only thing that shows in the browser are the text fields and submit button, the file upload field is nowhere in the page or html for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this look wrong to you:

> '#type '        => 'file',

it's not `'#type'`

Comment: This is what the Form API uses.  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#file                                                   Also every other example I can find: https://drupal.org/node/220944                    ,                           https://drupal.org/node/85922                               Also, if you know it is incorrect, why not show the correct way? It's a question and answer service, I'm not here for me to say something's not working and for someone to say "You did it wrong".  We are here to help each other.

Comment: No, sigh ........ you have an extra space in `"#type "`. You don't have the array key `"#type"`. Scrutinize your code better.

Comment: I said "does this look wrong to you" and quoted 1 line from your code, and it said it's not this **exact** string: `"#type"`. If you don't read your code letter-for-letter these types of errors will always get you.

I don't want to tell you literally "you have an extra space" because you don't learn how to read your code better -- you learn to ask others how debug your code for you.

You may not approve of my methods but I am trying to help you; while not spelling out the answer for as the error *not* an API question, its a syntax issue. Thanks for your time.